# Why does Axii sign not work?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The *Axii* sign should allow Geralt to get one enemy to fight on his side for a short while. This sound extremely useful for fighting groups, but I was unable to get it to work so far.

What happens when I use it on an enemy is that he gets distracted for a second and some visual effect is visible on the enemy. But he doesn't attack other enemies and the whole thing lasts only a second or so.

Am I doing something wrong, or does the *Axii* sign just not work on many enemies?

Comment: Are there levels associated with this in any way?  Maybe it starts out with that and works up to "full control".  Or were you using it on an [immune opponent](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Axii_sign)?

Comment: The manual's description (see this [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22538/how-can-i-tell-what-my-spells-do/22566#22566)) implies that there's only a chance for success. Try using it to see if it works *eventually*?

Comment: also, you won't get any experience points from the kills of the controlled guy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found that you have to charge the sign for it to work. Just hold `Q` until you see the *Axii* animation on the enemy finishing. If you stop before the sign is fully charged it just won't work.

Comment: That is the crucial point of the Axii sign. Also affecting is the range. There is still a probability of hexing an enemy. Not all attempts will succeed

Comment: You can charge signs? Neato.

Comment: @Raven I've only seen it for Axii yet, I'm not sure if holding the button makes any difference for the other signs.