# Axii puppet allied, but not attacking

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have equipped and charged the axii sign of the puppet type and it does always make the enemy (drowner, bandit or alghoul) a friend. But with the exception of a group of drowners it never resulted in the puppet attacking the rest of the monsters.  I have not been able to repeat the situation so far.

Do I have to attack the mob beforehand? Or afterwards? Does it have to be a melee attack? I tend to do the sign right before the fight, as it takes awfully long. For instance, I axii puppeted one of two alghouls, and then walked towards them to make them aggressive. I had the advantage of just one alghoul following me, but never did I see them fighting amongst themselves.

My situation differs from the one in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22533/160089), which appears to be a problem of casting. My situation is like the one described [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/72849149). I haven’t equipped delusion.

Comment: Have you tried [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/521643320361086117)? It stated: You have to hold Q but it takes some time. Keep pressing Q until you hear a very light click. Otherwise it will stun and the enemy just stands there. If done properly the enemy immediately attacks another. It works best with humans, bandits in particular. The thread ended when the OP replied to this so it probably fixed it for him.

Comment: @Reflexive Yes. Thanks. I have changed the the idle times for my first alternate sign (Yrden) and I am pretty sure my axii puppet is casting correctly, because it takes much longer time than the ordinary axii, has different (close range) animation and doesn’t leave the opponent stunned (but walking around). I think he is my puppet. He just doesn’t attack anyone (neither me, nor other monsters). In the one drowner case it worked like a charm, so I suspect something is needed to turn his aggro towards his brethren... Also, I play on pc

Comment: @Joachim i don‘t think so, but can’t test anytime soon. Need to reinstall